# scroll in table to avoid overflow

Tags: html, css

```
table {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    /*position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 42%;*/
    position:absolute;
    top: 47%;
    left: 3%;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color:#a3d1ff
}
```

this css code does not working to add scrol to my table...any help??
when i add more data to the table the size of it increase.how to make the stable

Comment: According to CSS specifications, `table`'s will expand horizontally and vertically to show all content.  The `height` value is treated as a minimum value and `max-height` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set overflow to scroll for an element with `display: table`, which is default for `<table>` elements. Try setting the display of the table to `display: block`.

```
table {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    /*position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 42%;*/
    position:absolute;top: 47%;left: 3%;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: block; /* I added this line */
}
```

Check out the example: https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/48/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a table that can be scrolled, you can add a wrapping element and add the scroll bar to it as shown below.

On `.table-wrap`, set a value for `height` and `overflow: auto` to show scroll bars as needed.  If you want the block to have a shrink-to-wrap width, use `display: inline-block`.

You can center the inline-block using a combination of `margin-left: 50%` and then the CSS transform `translateX(-50%)`.

```css
table td {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-wrap {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%; /* if you want to center the table horizontally */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.1</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.2</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.3</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.4</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.5</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text 1.6</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>Text 3</td>
    <td>Text 4</td>
    <td>Text 5</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```